# Use iOS 16 environment variable while support older iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

There are some new environment variable I need to use, for example

```
@Environment(\.requestReview) var requestReview // StoreKit
```

But my app needs to support older iOS. How do I "wrap" around this environment variable while not using iOS 16?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own extension for `EnvironmentValues` & in it do the check:

```
extension EnvironmentValues {
    var requestReviewOld: SomeType? {
        get {
            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                self.requestReview
            }else {
                nil
            }
        }
        set {
            if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                self.requestReview = newValue
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work for environment properties that change dynamically, like `isLuminanceReduced`, right?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could come up with a more idiomatic solution that would promote the usage of `@Environment` variables as the original API does, but declaring a new `ViewModifier` does the trick.

Start by declaring a new `ViewModifier`, followed by its extension, to make it available on `View`:

```
@available(iOS 16, *)
struct StoreReviewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var canRequestReview: Bool

    @Environment(\.requestReview) var requestReview

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onChange(of: canRequestReview) { newValue in
                if newValue {
                    requestReview.callAsFunction()
                }
            }
    }
}

public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func requestReview(_ canRequestReview: Binding<Bool>) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 16, *) {
            modifier(StoreReviewModifier(canRequestReview: canRequestReview))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use it as follows:

```
@State private var canRequestReview = false
    
var body: some View {
    ContentView()
        .requestReview($canRequestReview)
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this how to add support for requesting review on iOS 15?

Answer (score 1):

We need to annotate view holding that, like

```
@available(iOS 16, *)
struct StoreKitView: View {
    @Environment(\.requestReview) var requestReview

// ...
```

Comment: But you can use that view in iOS 16 only. It is not an ideal solution..

Answer (score 1):

The Environment is a global variable, so it could be obtain this way:

```
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct WidgetMarginsProvider: View
{
    @Environment(\.widgetContentMargins) var margins
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.clear
    }
}

extension View
{
    var widgetContentMargins: EdgeInsets {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *)
        {
            return WidgetMarginsProvider().margins
        }
        else
        {
            return EdgeInsets(16, 16, 16, 16)
        }
    }
}

struct ExampleView: View
{
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
            .padding(widgetContentMargins)
    }
}
```

Update, so above solution won't work because @Environment only work in the view block.

New solution:

Check this link: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733780

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34685436)