# How to declare SwiftUI environment variable when it's only available in a newer iOS version than your deployment target?

Tags: ios, swiftui

The iOS 17 SDK adds a `widgetContentMargins` environment variable you can add like so:

```
@Environment(\.widgetContentMargins) var margins
```

When your deployment target is less than 17, you get an error:

```
'widgetContentMargins' is only available in application extensions for iOS 17.0 or newer
```

The fix offered is to annotate your widget view as `@available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *)` but this of course doesn't work as you need your widget to be compatible with iOS versions older than 17.

How can you add this environment variable to utilize on iOS 17+ but keep compatibility with iOS 16 where you won't utilize it?

Comment: See [Use iOS 16 environment variable while support older iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73316438) for answers on the same issue w.r.t. iOS 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating `ViewModifier` which is being used only if certain OS version is available. This solution also allows you to choose edges to apply the modifier. You can also update this solution as you need.

```
@available(iOS 17, *)
struct WidgetContentMarginsModifier: ViewModifier {

    @Environment(\.widgetContentMargins) var widgetContentMargins

    var edge: Edge.Set

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(
                EdgeInsets(
                    top: edge.contains(.top) ? widgetContentMargins.top : 0,
                    leading: edge.contains(.leading) ? widgetContentMargins.leading : 0,
                    bottom: edge.contains(.bottom) ? widgetContentMargins.bottom : 0,
                    trailing: edge.contains(.trailing) ? widgetContentMargins.trailing : 0
                )
            )
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder func addWidgetContentMargins(_ edge: Edge.Set = .all) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 17, *) {
            modifier(WidgetContentMarginsModifier(edge: edge))
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Something")
        .addWidgetContentMargins()
}
```

or

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Something")
        .addWidgetContentMargins(.top)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use property like below

```
var margins: EdgeInsets {
    get {
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *) {
            @Environment(\.widgetContentMargins) var contentMargin
            return contentMargin
        } else {
            return EdgeInsets(
                top: 0,
                leading: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                trailing: 0
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this is not how the `@Environment` property wrapper is used, don't do this.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like below :

```
struct WidgetContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.widgetContentMargins) var margins
    
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *), let margins = margins {
            Text("Widget Content")
                .padding(.horizontal, margins.leading + margins.trailing)
                .padding(.vertical, margins.top + margins.bottom)
        } else {
            Text("Widget Content")
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```